# UIL images load again and again in listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I have a listview which contains only ten items, each items contains 5 images.

Adding data like this...

```
HomeCardListItemAdapter adapter = new HomeCardListItemAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.home_cardlist_item, FriendCards);
```

Initializes Image loader with this configuration on my very first activity.

```
    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(this, "FriendCache");
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
    .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) 
    .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
    .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

And in my HomeCardListItemAdapter I am displaying pictures like this... Adding whole getview method below.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    HomeCardDetails rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null || position == 0) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_cardlist_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.LLPaddingHelper = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LLPaddingHelper);
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVUserName);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IVProfilePic);
        holder.pb = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pb);
        holder.txtInteraction1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInteraction1);
        holder.IVInteraction1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IVInteraction1);
        holder.txtInteraction2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInteraction2);
        holder.IVInteraction2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IVInteraction2);
        holder.txtInterest1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInterest1);
        holder.IVInterest1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IVInterest1);
        holder.txtInterest2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInterest2);
        holder.IVInterest2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IVInterest2);
        holder.RLProfileLink = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RLProfileLink);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(position == 0)
    {
    }else{
        holder.LLPaddingHelper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    holder.txtName.setText(rowItem.Name);
    display(holder.imageView, rowItem.photoUrl.concat("?type=small"), holder.pb);

    if(rowItem.Interactions.size() >= 2){
        holder.txtInteraction1.setText(rowItem.Interactions.get(0).Name);
        display(holder.IVInteraction1, rowItem.Interactions.get(0).photoUrl);
        holder.txtInteraction2.setText(rowItem.Interactions.get(1).Name);
        display(holder.IVInteraction2, rowItem.Interactions.get(1).photoUrl);
    }

    if(rowItem.Interests.size() >= 2){
        holder.txtInterest1.setText(rowItem.Interests.get(0).Name);
        display(holder.IVInterest1, rowItem.Interests.get(0).photoUrl);
        holder.txtInterest2.setText(rowItem.Interests.get(1).Name);
        display(holder.IVInterest2, rowItem.Interests.get(1).photoUrl);
    }

    return convertView;

}
```

And these are my display functions.

```
    public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner){

    imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        boolean cacheFound;

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            List<String> memCache = MemoryCacheUtils.findCacheKeysForImageUri(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
            cacheFound = !memCache.isEmpty();
            if (!cacheFound) {
                File discCache = DiskCacheUtils.findInCache(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());
                if (discCache != null) {
                    cacheFound = discCache.exists();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (cacheFound) {
                MemoryCacheUtils.removeFromCache(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
                DiskCacheUtils.removeFromCache(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());

                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, (ImageView) view);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

    });
}

public void display(ImageView img, String url)
{
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        boolean cacheFound;

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            List<String> memCache = MemoryCacheUtils.findCacheKeysForImageUri(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
            cacheFound = !memCache.isEmpty();
            if (!cacheFound) {
                File discCache = DiskCacheUtils.findInCache(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());
                if (discCache != null) {
                    cacheFound = discCache.exists();
                }
            }
            }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (cacheFound) {
                MemoryCacheUtils.removeFromCache(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
                DiskCacheUtils.removeFromCache(imageUri, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());

                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, (ImageView) view);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

});
}
```

This is my DisplayImageoption in my adapter

```
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.image_loading_logo)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(5))
        .build();
```

My problem is that when I wait on first item till its all images loaded, then go to last item (mean 10 th item) and go back to first item, its all images loads again. This problem is not only with first item it happens with all items.

Comment: Each time a row is out of view, it gets destroyed and then recreated once it comes into view when you scroll up or down, if the image is not hitting your cache then the problem would be there.

Comment: But why it is taking time to load when it is already downloaded and cached? 
I have gridview with hundreds of images and cache run perfect on that with same config.

Comment: is the images size bigger?? i guess it takes time for GC and/or for loading images into the `imageview`

Comment: Can I make my list not destroy on going out of the view? As I have just ten items in my whole list

Comment: In `onLoadingComplete` the `cache` is cleared everytime its found ?? and one cannot control the destruction of the view since its the behaviour of android.

Comment: Yes I got that now, I found out on a question that it will refresh image with new one thats why I added this. But removing that solved my issue :)

Comment: cool :) In future you may same problem with images that are big in size, that time you can apply this `http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html`